# How do I write the partial derivatives without partitioning?

Tags: fractions

I have this code:

```
D_{1}\equiv - \frac{\partial^2 EU }{\partial \alpha \partial \widebar{d}}
```

which yields

[image]

I want to write this expression differently. Like this for example

[image]

Comment: What's the problem in typing `\partial EU/\partial\alpha`?

Comment: `\partial^2 EU/\partial \alpha \partial \widebar{d}`

Comment: Why don't you like the `\frac{}{}` syntax? Mathematicians prefer this.

Comment: Maybe `nicefrac` package is what you want, just type `\nicefrac{\partial^EU}{\partial\alpha \partial\widebar{d}}`

Comment: Has \widebar been depreciated?  I keep getting "undefined control sequence" for it.  \overline works fine.  I updated all my packages last Friday.